# Continuously adjust element size as screen size changes

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, flexbox

Is there a way to use media queries to change the value of a CSS property gradually as the screen changes size (continuously/smoothly). Instead of setting a bunch of break points at which there is a change (step-ly)?

Like on this site: http://www.bluegoji.com/?
The margins of the `<a>` tags in the `<ul>` at the top of the page (navbar) decrease continuously as you narrow the browser window.

That is the behavior I am trying to achieve.

Or is the solution just to use so many media queries that it appears to change smoothly??

Answer (score 6):

Consider using ***viewport percentage units***.

From the spec:

> [**5.1.2. Viewport-percentage lengths: the `vw`, `vh`, `vmin`, `vmax` units**](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values/#viewport-relative-lengths)
>
> The viewport-percentage lengths are relative to the size of the
>   initial containing block. When the height or width of the initial
>   containing block is changed, they are scaled accordingly.
>
> - **vw unit** - Equal to 1% of the width of the initial containing block.
> - **vh unit** - Equal to 1% of the height of the initial containing
>     block.
> - **vmin unit** - Equal to the smaller of `vw` or `vh`.
> - **vmax unit** - Equal to the larger of `vw` or `vh`.

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/244ev4L7/3/)

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is not media queries.
You can set widths, margins and padding in percentages. That is the normal way of doing this.

Here is an example:

HTML

```
<div>
    <a>Link</a>
    <a>Link</a>
    <a>Link</a>
    <a>Link</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
a {
    width:25%;
    display:block;
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The example you gave uses flexbox like this:

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
}
li {
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  text-align:center;
  outline: 1px solid silver;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 500px){
  ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  li {
    flex-grow: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>
```