# How to put the footer div below the content?

Tags: html, css

I have this code here: http://jsfiddle.net/52yekaL9/

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.content {
  height: 100%;
}

.part {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.a { background-color: red; }
.b { background-color: green; }
.c { background-color: blue; }
.d { background-color: orange; }
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="part a">1</div>
  <div class="part b" style="height:150px;">2</div>
  <div class="part c">3</div>
</div>
<div class="footer d">
  this footer
</div>
```

The problem is in my `div.footer d`. I see that it is in this form: `div.part b`. I was testing and I see if I change the **height** of `.content`, the footer moves as well.

But I don´t think the correct way to change is: `200% + 150px`

Is there another way to put the footer div after the content div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of [***percentage heights***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276) (which are overly complicated and tricky), use [***viewport percentage units***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36506926/3597276), which are simple, stable and reliable:

```css
.content {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.part {
  height: 100vh;
}

.a { background-color: red; }
.b { background-color: green; } 
.c { background-color: blue; }
.d { background-color: orange; }
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="part a">1</div>
  <div class="part b" style="height:150px;">2</div>
  <div class="part c">3</div>
</div>
<div class="footer d">this footer</div>
```

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vtxzvn2u/)

Comment: Is this better in the screen percert cases use the viewport percentage units?

Comment: @jtwalters, I'm sorry I don't understand the question.

Comment: @Michael_B I think he's asking if using viewport is better when you set width and height as percentages.

Comment: Thanks, @SittingBull. Generally speaking, use *percentages* when you want to size an element relative to the parent. You normally need to define a height on the parent for this to work (there are exceptions).

Comment: @Michael_B, In cases of my reference is the screen like the problem or maybe: "I need a width of div in 30% of screen" is better use `width: 30vw;` than `width: 30%;`?

Comment: Use *viewport percentages* when you are able to size elements relative to the *initial containing block* (i.e., the viewport). Since you were trying to set your elements to `height: 100%`, using `height: 100vh` was an easy and simple alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="part a">1</div>
  <div class="part b" style="height:150px;">2</div>
  <div class="part c">3</div>
  <div class="footer d">
  this footer
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're putting the footer inside 'content' and he does not want the footer to be manipulated when he manipulates content.