# How to make a canvas contained in width and height in a flex div?

Tags: css, canvas, flexbox

TL;DR: here is a full page example: https://jsfiddle.net/rfp8xv6g/show (editable here: https://jsfiddle.net/rfp8xv6g), how to make that the canvas (with purple border) is fully contained vertically in the container, without hardcoding a height?

---

Here is a simplified example. I have the following layout (click "Full page" in the snippet to be able to see it).

The left column contains a wrapper containing several `<canvas>` on top of each other (here only one canvas for simplicity).

Problem: if the canvas width/height is high (in canvas coordinate system, here 4000x3000), then the full canvas is not visible (too high in height, it grows out of the viewport).

**How to make that the canvas is scaled/shrinked to be contained in the left column?** (without a page vertical scrollbar)

Here `max-width: 100%;` *works* in order to have the canvas contained **horizontally**.

But `max-height: 100%;` doesn't do any effect: the canvas is not contained vertically, why?

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body, 
.page {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.page {
  background-color: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.left-column {
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
}

.right-column {
  background-color: orange;
  flex: 1;
}

canvas {
  border: 3px solid magenta;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="left-column">
    <div class="canvas-wrapper">
      <canvas width="4000" height="3000"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-column">
    RIGHT
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you seeking a CSS-only solution?

Comment: @obscure Yes, preferably.

Comment: @obscure Here is a full example: https://jsfiddle.net/rfp8xv6g/show

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the `canvas` to adapt to the height of the flex element, then you do not need to specify the `align-items: center;` value in the flex container. Or you need to add `align-self: stretch;` to the flex element.
You can also use `flexbox` for centering canvases container.

In fact, all the code to solve your problem boils down to:

```css
.zone-left-column {
  align-self: stretch;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.canvas-wrapper {
  min-height: 0;
}
```

---

Below is a complete example:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body,
.page {
  height: 100%;
}

.page {
  max-width: 70rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.toolbar {
  background-color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.5);
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex: 0 0 5rem;
}

.container {
  background-color: red;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  gap: 2rem;
}

.flex-horizontal {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.zone-left-column {
  background-color: green;
  /* add  */
  align-self: stretch;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.canvas-wrapper {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .4);
  /* must have  */
  min-height: 0;
}

canvas {
  border: 3px solid magenta;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.zone-right-column {
  background-color: orange;
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="toolbar">
    TOOLBAR
  </div>
  <div class="container flex-horizontal">
    <div class="zone-left-column">
      <div class="canvas-wrapper">
        <canvas width="2000" height="1500"></canvas>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="zone-right-column">
      RIGHT
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I see it works, but I don't know exactly why: why is `min-height: 0` important, and what does it do exactly?

Comment: Thanks for choosing my answer, glad to help. `min-height: 0;` is required so that the element can shrink, because by default when `overflow: visible;` it is set to `min-height: auto;`. You can also change the `overflow` value to anything other than `visible` in the element. [Automatic minimum size of Flex elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#min-size-auto)

Comment: I am still trying to understand why min-height makes its child 100% height of its "grandparent" but it kind of does the job.

Comment: @Salman A I provided a link to the specification in a previous comment. Perhaps the `min-height` is a bit confusing here, because our main axis comes from `flex-direction: column;`. Here is an example from `flex-direction: row;`: [codepen](https://codepen.io/imhvost/pen/abRabEB) Best Regards! ✌️

Answer (score 0):

When an element has a percentage height, the parent must have a defined height.

If the parent has no defined height, then the percentage height simply resolves to `auto`.

Here's a complete explanation:

- [Working with the CSS `height` property and percentage values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276)

You have at least two available solutions:

1. Define a height on the parent (`.canvas-wrapper`) or, even better in this case,
2. Use [*viewport percentage units*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36506926/3597276) (e.g., `vh`) instead of *percentage units* (`%`).

Make one adjustment to your code:

```
canvas {
  border: 3px solid magenta;
  max-width: 100%;
  /* max-height: 100%; */
   max-height: 100vh; /* new */
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body, 
.page {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.page {
  background-color: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.left-column {
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
}

.right-column {
  background-color: orange;
  flex: 1;
}

canvas {
  border: 3px solid magenta;
  max-width: 100%;
  /* max-height: 100%; */
   max-height: 100vh; /* new */
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="left-column">
    <div class="canvas-wrapper">
      <canvas width="4000" height="3000"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-column">
    RIGHT
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much @MichaelBenjamin for your answer! In fact in my case, it cannot use 100 % of vertical viewport, because there is a top toolbar (which I omitted for simplicity), see https://jsfiddle.net/rfp8xv6g/. How would you do in this case? Thanks again!

Comment: Here is the full screen version: https://jsfiddle.net/rfp8xv6g/show

Comment: Use the `calc()` function: `max-height: calc(100vh - 8rem)` (so, the full height, less the height of the toolbar (`5rem`), less the padding and margin (`3em`). https://jsfiddle.net/yfwvnbu6/

Comment: Thanks @MichaelBenjamin! Is there a way without hardcoding the toolbar height, and more in the spirit of `flex` / flex-grow etc. : "let it grow vertically until there is no remaining space"? Could flex do this automatically?

Comment: Set a height on the container. Then you can set the `canvas` height to `max-height: 100%`. Because the container is a flex container in column direction, the canvas (a flex item) will shrink to fit (because the default setting of `flex-shrink` is `1`).

Comment: Thank you @MichaelBenjamin. Devil is in the detail, but I can't do it in the full example (full page: https://jsfiddle.net/rfp8xv6g/show) *without hardcoding the toolbar height with calc* when setting the container height. Would you have a solution on https://jsfiddle.net/rfp8xv6g? Thanks a lot! I started a bounty because I can't find a solution.

Comment: So you want a solution without the `flex: 0 0 5rem` on the `.toolbar`? https://jsfiddle.net/7q2uepfL/

Comment: I thought I solved the problem @MichaelBenjamin, but finally there's always a little something that doesn't work, I'm tearing my hair out since days :) My latest version: https://gget.it/tpif/page4.html. Last problem: when you zoom out in the browser (90% 80% 70% etc. with `<CTRL> <->`) then the canvas wrapper is not vertically aligned in the middle, it stays on top. Every time I try a solution that solves this, it destroys something else. A last idea based on this .html page? :) Thanks one million times!

Comment: Add this: `.canvas-wrapper { display: flex; align-items: center }`

Comment: It works indeed @MichaelBenjamin! https://gget.it/p2nw/page5.html The only issue I will probably have is that, as I need to stack multiple canvas on top of each other (multiple layers), I needed `.canvas-wrapper` to be *of the same size than the canvas* themselves. Here instead `.canvas-wrapper` (of grey background) takes the full height of the container and not *only* the size of the canvas: https://gget.it/qi6o/20230509_221717_1257a0c2.png Maybe you have an idea about this detail? I promiss it's the last one :)

Comment: Add `align-items: center` to `.zone-left-column`. (You can now remove the code from my last post.)

Comment: Thank you for your help @MichaelBenjamin! This is the update with your last comment: https://gget.it/0bdc/page7.html. (Still some issues when we zoom in, but I think the problem is solved with another method, see my linked SO question). Thanks a lot again for your help.

Comment: @Michael Benjamin , Allow me to slightly disagree with you. It is not necessary to set the height directly on the parent. A father can be flexible. Also, according to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31728022/why-is-percentage-height-not-working-on-my-div/31728799#31728799), everything is not so clear with `min-height` 

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and for posting an answer. Let's see what OP thinks. @imhvost

Comment: @Michael Benjamin , Added my comment to your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31728022/why-is-percentage-height-not-working-on-my-div/31728799#31728799). Best regards.